# How to ask the user if they wish to input another value in c

Tags: c

This is how i attempted it, how ever when i enter q it just skips a line in command and continues the program.

```
int main()
{
int a;
char c;
cont(&a);
while(a != 'q' && a != 'Q')
{
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF)
{
    putchar( r13( c ) );    
 }
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: if homework please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the reference of `a` to `cont()` -

```
void cont(int* a)
{ 
    printf("If you do not want to enter a value press q"); 
    scanf("%c", a);
}
```

and call it like that:

```
cont(&a);
```

otherwise, only the the copy of `a` (that is passed to the function) is changed, not `a` itself.

If you want to change the value of `a` in the function, then you need to store the return value somewhere, but you ignored it (e.g. `a = cont(a);`).
Or, give a reference (e.g. address of) a to the function, so it will be able to change the value of `a`.

Comment: Or, alternatively say **a = cont(a)**

Comment: I tried that but i get this error: type missmatch in redeclaration of cont

Comment: @d-live - seems like I wasn't clear enough in the second part of my answer, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: ty, i have a ogood idea, ill fix it all up, and see how it goes thanks

Comment: @user754346 - that's because you haven't declare `cont` before main. Add this line, before main: `void cont(int *a);`. and read about declaration here: http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html

Comment: Ok, i got the quit workign at start, but if you dotn cancel at start it will keep running, tried alot of things here already not sure what else to do.

Comment: That's because your inner loop keeps running with no control (until EOF - ctrl+d in most systems).

Comment: I know its because of that, no idea how to make it stop by putting in Q.